# Value for sum of inverse of Gaussian integers

Tags: complex-numbers, integer-lattices, gaussian-integers

So I was studying some stuff about lattices and at some point I reached the *Eisenstein series of weight 2k* given by $$G_{2k}(\Lambda)=\sum_{w\in\Lambda-\{0\}}w^{-2k}$$
Then I tried to think about "easy" cases of such series so I thought "let's see what happens when I take $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}[i]$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $k=1$ but couldn't really get a nice value for it, or there is no such nice value?

Thanks

Comment: Since $\{ iw|w\in \Lambda\}=\Lambda$, one has $G_2(\Lambda)=-G_2(\Lambda)$.

Comment: Oh boy! nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found something useful on *Complex Analysis*, Stein & Shakarchi, chapter 9. They give an equivalent formula for the general case, so in this particular one $$G_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-8\pi^2\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\sigma(r)e^{-2\pi r}$$ where $\sigma(r)$ is the sum of the divisors of *r*, which is good for now.